# Excel VBA Method 'ClearContents' of Object Range Failed

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp

I've looked at the similar questions about "Method of Object Range Failed" but none seem to help me solve my problem.

The error I receive is: "Method 'ClearContents' of Object Range Failed"

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is that if cell value of BG21 = 1 And the length of the string in adjacent cell (BH21) is 0 Then timestamp the adjacent cell (BH21). Ideally I want to repeat this for Range (BG21:BG35). I know I could use a for each method but I want to get this error cleared first.

I don't want to use the cell formula because I need a timestamp the moment the cell BG21 changes to 1. If I use a cell formula then anytime the workbook is opened the timestamp changes.

The code I have is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Submittal Kickoff Meeting")

    If (ws.Range("$BG$21").Value = 1 And len(ws.Range("$BH$21").Value) = 0 And Target.Address = ws.Range("$BG$21")) Then
        ws.Range("$BH$21").Value = Format(Now(), "m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    Else
        ws.Range("$BH$21").ClearContents  '<--- Error occurs here
    End If
End Sub
```

The error occurs on line:

```
ws.Range("$BH$21").ClearContents
```

I have also tried:

```
ws.Range("$BH$21").Value = ""
```

But I received the same error code

Any advice??

.

Comment: Could you not start the code as `If Target.Address = "$BH$21" Then` This is a worksheet_change event, you don't require to set variables for the sheet, because you are already on the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get the error, but there are two things in your code you made wrong.

1. `Target.Address = ws.Range("$BG$21")` Default property for `Range` is `Value`, so you compare Address with Value here.
2. `ws.Range("$BH$21").ClearContents` will cause infinite loop, as this code changes worksheet, so `Change` event occurs and macro starts again. Use `EnableEvents` to avoid this.

   ```
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   ws.Range("$BH$21").ClearContents
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have it cycling through an infinite loop due to you editing the file when you change the value of BH21. You will need another if or something else to avoid the infinite loop. Mine worked just fine with editing cell with a blank.

You should also change your if statement from

```
Target.Address = ws.Range("$BG$21")
```

to

```
Target.Address = "$BG$21"
```